# scaling an SVG over an image that resizes without jquery

Tags: html, svg

lets suppose I have an image of dimensions `1280x720`

I have some polygons that are computed by a server on top of the original sized images that need to be drawn on top of this image. They are

```
<polygon points="531,243,687,316,663,593,360,717,191,520" />                                    
<polygon points="275,17,422,45,412,312,271,235" />
<polygon points="929,180,1108,248,985,707,847,676" />
<polygon points="598,70,700,101,658,531,516,436" />
```

Now I need to display the image and overlay these polygons on top of it. The problem however is that the image is scaled by  the browser depending on the window size, which is dynamic. The image is displayed using `object-fit-contain` CSS so the size changes as I resize.

How do I ensure the SVG co-ordinates above auto scale?

I've read about viewBox but I'm not really looking to specify my own co-ordinates here. The issue is I don't really know how the image will be displayed/sized by the browser as it will depend on the window.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default scaling behaviour of SVGs is the same as `object-fit: contain`. So all you should need to do is set the SVG's `viewBox` width and height to the same dimensions as the image.

So, for instance, if your image is 640x480, set your viewBox to `"0 0 640 480"`.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

div > img,
div > svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

img {
  object-fit: contain;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg"/>
  
  <svg viewBox="0 0 640 480">
    <circle cx="450" cy="215" r="40" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="10"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Paul thanks, I posted details of issues I am facing using viewBox in another question as this question did not have all the details  - let me know if I should instead just edit this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41416484/is-svg-resizing-this-hard-what-am-i-missing

Answer (score 0):

Could you avoid doing this with html in any way? A simple image editor seems like a better way of doing this, but I can't say because I don't know your circumstances. Otherwise you could probably use margin for the placement.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the img tag is a live camera feed the server sends that keeps changing. I need to display "alarm zones" on top of it which are the polygons (this data also comes from the server via an API)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<image>` element inside the `<svg>` tag, then they will become one, you can do any scale with it.

Here is an SVG image example:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <rect x="10" y="10" height="130" width="500" style="fill: #000000"/>

  <image x="20" y="20" width="300" height="80"
     xlink:href="http://jenkov.com/images/layout/top-bar-logo.png" />

  <line x1="25" y1="80" x2="350" y2="80"
            style="stroke: #ffffff; stroke-width: 3;"/>
</svg>
```

Reference: [SVG image element](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/image-element.html#svg-image-video)