# Is SVG resizing this hard ? What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

I am trying to write code that resizes an SVG overlay on top of an image. The server I am working with returns both the image and via an API, a list of polygon points I need to overlay on top of the image.

This is what it should look like (the image below is a correctly aligned SVG layer). The image size is 1280x720 (I've scaled it down)
[image]

What I need to do in my app (ionic v1 app) is to make sure the SVG overlay resizes as the browser window resizes and it seems to be very hard. Here is my approach:

I am trapping a window resize event and when the image is resized, I scale the SVG polygon points relative to the size of the drawn window as it seems there is really no way to "automatically" scale the SVG by the browser like it does with an image.

[Here is my code pen](http://codepen.io/pliablepixels/pen/apoJyj) as you see it doesn't work as intended when I rescale (and for that matter in when its full size the overlays are not accurate). The overlays don't look accurate and when I resize it all messed up. Can someone help?

Given SO needs a code block for codepen links here it is, but its just easier to look at the codepen if you want to run it

CSS:

```
.imagecontainer{position:relative; margin:0 auto;}

.zonelayer
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:none;

}

.zonelayer polygon {
    fill-opacity: 0.25;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

.Active {
    stroke: #ff0000;
    fill: #ff0000;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<ion-content>
        image:{{disp}}<br/>
      <small>points: <span ng-repeat="item in zoneArray">{{item}}</span></small>
        <div class="imagecontainer">

            <img id="singlemonitor" style="width:100vw; height:100vh;object-fit:contain" ng-src="http://m9.i.pbase.com/o9/63/103963/1/164771719.2SfdldRy.nphzms.jpeg"  />
            <div class="zonelayer">
                <svg ng-attr-width="{{cw}}" ng-attr-height="{{ch}}" class="zonelayer" ng-attr-viewBox="0 0 {{cw}} {{ch}}">
                    <polygon ng-repeat="item in zoneArray"  ng-attr-points="{{item}}" class="Active"/> </polygon>

                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>

    </ion-content>
```

JS controller:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', liveloaded);
  liveloaded();
  // credit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41411891/most-elegant-way-to-parse-scale-and-re-string-a-string-of-number-co-ordinates?noredirect=1#41411927
    function scaleCoords(string, sx, sy) {
        var f = [sx, sy];
        return string.split(' ').map(function (a) {
            return a.split(',').map(function (b, i) {
                return Math.round(b * f[i]);
            }).join(',');
        }).join(' ');
    }

  function liveloaded()
  {

        $timeout (function () {
                    console.log ("IMAGE LOADED");
                    var img =document.getElementById("singlemonitor");

                    //var offset = img.getBoundingClientRect();
                    $scope.cw = img.clientWidth;
                    $scope.ch = img.clientHeight;
                    $scope.vx = img.offsetWidth;
                    $scope.vy = img.offsetHeight;

                    var rect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
                    //console.log(rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left);
                    $scope.disp = img.clientWidth+ "x"+img.clientHeight + " with offsets:"+$scope.vx+"/"+$scope.vy;

                    $scope.zoneArray = [
                    "598,70 700,101 658,531 516,436",
                    "531,243 687,316 663,593 360,717 191,520",
                    "929,180 1108,248 985,707 847,676",
                    "275,17 422,45 412,312 271,235",
                    ];

                    var ow = 1280;
                    var oh = 720;

                    for (var i=0; i < $scope.zoneArray.length; i++)
                    {
                        var sx = $scope.cw/ow;
                        var sy = $scope.ch/oh;
                        $scope.zoneArray[i] = scaleCoords($scope.zoneArray[i],sx,sy);
                        console.log ("SCALED:"+$scope.zoneArray[i]);
                    }


                });
            }
```

Comment: "Given SO needs a code block for codepen links here it is" - no, don't do that. Just include your code in the post rather than trying to trick the filter!

Comment: done - the reason I did that is there were various sections to post for it to make sense and the codepen just has all of it working and running

Comment: Is there a reason you can't load the SVG into an `<img />` element and let the browser resize it for you?

Comment: I'd love to be able to do that, but the server returns the points via an API that are dynamically retrieved in my app (The hard-coded co-ords in the example were a simplification). How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Why are you saying "there is really no way to "automatically" scale the SVG by the browser like it does with an image"? You very obviously can: just set the viewBox on your SVG to the original size, and resize the SVG. Alternatively, you could just apply a transform on the SVG element or any of its children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

The main problem is you can't use `ng-attr-viewBox`, because angular will "normalise" the attribute to lower case.  It turns the attribute into `viewbox` (lower case B) which is (currently) invalid. `viewBox` is case sensitive.

The solution is to use a special trick of Angular to preserve camel-case.  If you use `ng-attr-view_box`, it will generate the correctly camel-cased attribute name of `viewBox`.

```
<svg width="100vw" height="100vh" class="zonelayer" ng-attr-view_box="0 0 {{cw}} {{ch}}">
```

The other thing is that you are using the wrong width and height values for the viewBox.  You need to use the natural/intrinsic image dimensions in your viewBox.

```
$scope.cw = img.naturalWidth;
$scope.ch = img.naturalHeight;
```

[Link to updated code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBvpXP)

Comment: Thanks Paul. I did a quick check - works on Chrome, but the SVGs don't show up at all on Safari. Am in the process of debugging!

Comment: Not quite sure what the problem was with your codepen, but incorporating your suggestions in my codepen  http://codepen.io/pliablepixels/pen/apoJyj works perfectly! Doing more testing. That viewBox trick was impossible for me to have figured out (given my knowledge). Thanks!

Comment: Paul, quick question, If I change the image from `object-fit:contain` to `object-fit:cover` what sorcery do I need for the svg to map correctly? Changing its style to the same object-fit doesn't seem to work at all

Comment: Adding the following to your `<svg>` tag should do it: `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"`

Comment: Thanks - `ng-attr-preserve_aspect_ratio={{ar}}` where ar = "none" or "xMidYMid slice" (because I need to toggle between fill and contain) doesn't seem to be working (your suggestion works, my ng-attr aproach is not)

Comment: Oops - was a bug in my code. Fixed and it works great. Thanks for the awesome help, Paul!

Comment: The default value of `preserveAspectRatio` (equivalent to `contain`), is not `none`. It is `xMidYMid meet`. Which I guess is the bug you were referring to(?)

Comment: Yes, that was it. Also, I was wondering if you might have time for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41452295/zooming-an-image-results-in-issues-with-pagex-pagey-to-svg-conversions