# zooming an image results in issues with pageX/pageY to SVG conversions

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to move a SVG circle that sits in the center of an HTML image. If you mouse down on the image and drag the circle it works great.

However, if I zoom the image (tap on + button in the codepen), pageX and pageY to SVG co-ordinate translation messes up.

How should I be handling this correctly ? (My complete code handles both touch and mouse events for SVG - I've simplified it to just mouse for this example)

My codepen: http://codepen.io/pliablepixels/pen/EZxyRN

Here is how I am getting co-ordinates (please see codepen for a runnable example):

```
 // map to SVG view so I can move the circle
  function recompute(ax,ay)
  {
   // alert ("Here");
        var svg=document.getElementById('zsvg');
        var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
        pt.x = ax;
        pt.y = ay;
        var svgP = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
        $scope.cx = Math.round(svgP.x);
        $scope.cy = Math.round(svgP.y);


  }

  function moveit(event)
  {

     if (!isDrag) return;
     var status = "Dragging with X="+event.pageX+" Y="+event.pageY;

    $timeout (function(){$scope.status = status; recompute(event.pageX, event.pageY)});
  }
```

The relevant SVG:

```
<svg   id = "zsvg" class="zonelayer" viewBox="0 0 400 200" width="400" height="300" >
  <circle id="c1" ng-attr-cx="{{cx}}" ng-attr-cy="{{cy}}" r="20" stroke="blue" fill="purple"  />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you would normally use `clientX` and `clientY` rather than `pageX` and `pageY`.

Secondly, the Ionic(?) `zoomTo()` function you are using is applying a 3D transform to the container div. Ie.

```
style="transform: translate3d(-791.5px, -173px, 0px) scale(2);"
```

I don't expect `getScreenCTM()` handles 3D transforms.  Even ones that are effectively 2D because they do nothing in the Z axis.

You'll need to either:

1. do the zoom a different way. IOW handle it yourself so you can do it in a `getScreenCTM()`-friendly way. Or multiply the zoom factor in directly. *or*
2. find a way of getting the details of the transform that Ionic has applied and updating your transformed mouse coords appropriately.

**Update:**

The definition of `getScreenCTM()` has changed in SVG 2.  In SVG 1.1 it was [fairly loosely defined](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#types-__svg__SVGLocatable__getScreenCTM). In SVG 2 [the definition has been updated](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#types-__svg__SVGGraphicsElement__getScreenCTM) to explicitly define how the result is calculated.  Although it does not specify how 3D transforms on ancestor elements should be handled.

[I have experimented a little](https://jsfiddle.net/r8887x05/1/) on Chrome and Firefox.  It appears that Chrome has implemented the SVG2 definition, but it has a bug. It is not returning the correct transform matrix.  However Firefox has not yet been updated. It is not including any transforms on ancestor elements.

I now believe the bug in Chrome is the reason your sample is not working there.  However if you want to be cross-browser, my advice to handle zoom yourself - and adjust the transform (or coords) - still holds.

Comment: Chrome bug reported here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=678167

Comment: Wow, thanks Paul. This turned out to be more complicated that I had assumed. Thanks for getting to the  core problem. I think its easiest if I just figure out a way to disable zoom if I am dragging SVG points around.

Comment: It's fairly easy to do yourself.  As long as your SVG has a `viewBox`, all you need to do to zoom is to alter the `width` and `height` attributes. Your dragging should all work perfectly.

Comment: oh? My use-case is actually for the image to be zoomed in and out. I did not realize adapting the svg view box (it does have one) will achieve image zooming as well. I'll give it a whirl right now

Comment: Oh whoops, yes.  You'll need to scale the image at the same time. Or put the image inside the SVG instead.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was about to post a video of what I am really doing - the SVG sits on top of a camera feed and the use-case is to zoom the image of the feed in and out as we edit (because in mobile devices, touch on svg hardly works unless there is enough tappable area) https://youtu.be/chgXla97Y2U